# Pandasでcsvのヘッダー名がカラム名とならない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下の様なcsvファイルを
`test = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')`で読むと、
Date,Open,High・・・がカラム名として表示されるのですが、
`test['Date']`とするとKeyErrorとなります。
やっかいなことに、別のcsvファイルだとErrorとならず値が表示されたりするものがあり、
何でそうなるのかどなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか。

---

```
Date,Open,High,Low,close
2000-01-01,1200.00,1201.05,1200.00,1200.08
```

Comment: 可能性として、CSVファイルで `Date` の前後にスペースやタブ文字が入ってしまっているなどが考えられます。

Comment: 確かに、ヘッダーファイルのDateとOpenの間にスペースが入っていました。

Comment: 取り除いたところ、うまくいきました！！

Comment: 見た目はうまくいっていても、スペース入っているのは駄目なんですね。。。